# How to build an augmented reality airplane radar app?

Tags: augmented-reality, coordinate-transformation

I like to build an **augmented reality app** (iOS or Android) that allows to point the phone at the sky and **label the airplanes** in the air (overlay). I've got the planes' coordinates and altitude, and I know the phone's GPS position, including altitude and camera direction (based on magnetometer and gyroscope). I don't want to render any 3D stuff nor do I care about buildings or hills that are in the line of sight, so the task is "only" to draw the labels at the right position as overlay on the camera image.

I know about SDKs like Wikitude that might do the trick but I wonder how complex the above task is to do by hand? Coordinate transformation might be one thing, the other challenge might be to camera characteristics (focal length?) of all potential phone models... Are there any OS libraries that help here?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are locating planes in the air, you can safely ignore the focal length and other camera properties and issues because the distance to the plane will always be so much plane will always be will always be so much further than the focal length.

For actually detecting the plane, most AR SDKs aren't well suited to the task.  I'd start by using OpenCV to blur the image and then detect a circle.  If you have a blue sky with an airplane in the background that will work ok for a first pass

Comment: Thanks Dave. But given the fact I know the positions of the airplanes (from transponder data) and also my own position, I like to simply calculate where on the screen the planes are (since in case they are far away, they would be very hard to detect anyway on the camera image).